# Lambda function inside map pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am unable to comprehend the structure of this if else if else in the lambda function defined below. Particularly - the part :

```
if x != x
```

In this code :

```
check['Id'].map(lambda x: x if x != x else (str(x)[:str(x).rfind('.0')] if str(x).rfind('.0') != -1 else str(x))
```

PS: I get that above code is formatting the ID value and returning a string without the decimal that could be there in the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is for working with `NaN`s, because:

```
np.nan != np.nan
```

so if `NaN`s it return `NaN`s else processes strings.

Sample:

```
check = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[np.nan, '0909.0', '023', '09.06']})

a = check['Id'].map(lambda x: x if x != x else (str(x)[:str(x).rfind('.0')] if str(x).rfind('.0') != -1 else str(x)))
print (a)
0     NaN
1    0909
2     023
3      09
Name: Id, dtype: object
```

If omit it it working, because converting to strings, but first value is not `np.nan`, but string `nan`:

```
a = check['Id'].map(lambda x: (str(x)[:str(x).rfind('.0')] if str(x).rfind('.0') != -1 else str(x)))
print (a)
0     nan
1    0909
2     023
3      09
Name: Id, dtype: object
```

If all values are strings with `NaN`s and remove converting to strings:

```
a = check['Id'].map(lambda x: ((x)[:(x).rfind('.0')] if (x).rfind('.0') != -1 else (x)))
print (a)
```

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'rfind'

```
a = check['Id'].map(lambda x: x if x != x else ((x)[:(x).rfind('.0')] if (x).rfind('.0') != -1 else (x)))
print (a)
0     NaN
1    0909
2     023
3      09
Name: Id, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

As jezrael posted, it's just filtering out `NaN`values.
It's not the most pythonic or readable way to write it, though.

If you have problems running `NaN`'s through your lambda function, you should add the parameter `na_action='ignore'` so your map function *ignores* NaN's and avoids error.

So you should try:

```
map(lambda x:      your_function_here      , na_action='ignore')
```

Instead of:

```
map(lambda x: x if x != x else ( your_function_here ) )
```

You should expect the same results in both codes, but the first one is more pythonic and readable, as it clearly express we are ignoring Na values.