# Assign Variables Based on Datagrame Values

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, variables, finance

I have a dataframe in which I am trying to define variables according to the values of particular cells in the dataframe in order to populate a (currently) empty final column based on the relationship between the price targets and current prices of the companies. Currently, the dataframe I’m working with looks like this, with the index being the companies:

| Company | Current Price | High | Median | Low | Suggest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company 1 | $296.12 | $410.00 | $398.00 | $365.43 |  |
| Company 2 | $143.18 | $212.05 | $200.34 | $155.12 |  |
| Company 3 | $184.23 | $214.09 | $192.88 | $123.63 |  |

How would I assign a variables (for example: target_high(company) = value in the “ticker, target_high” cell)? I don't think I can hard code it because the list of companies will be constantly changing. So far I’ve tried the following but it doesn’t seem to work:

```
for ticker in Company_List:
    target_high(company) = str(Target_Frame.loc[ticker, "High"])
    target_mid(company) = str(Target_Frame.loc[ticker, "Median"])
    target_low(company) = str(Target_Frame.loc[ticker, "Low"])
    current_price = str(Target_Frame.loc[ticker, "Price"])
    if current_price(ticker) > target_high(ticker):
        Target_Frame.loc[[ticker], ['Suggest']] = "Sell"
    elif current_price(ticker) < target_low(ticker):
        Target_Frame.loc[[ticker], ['Suggest']] = "Buy"
    elif target_mid(ticker) < current_price(ticker) < target_high(ticker):
        Target_Frame.loc[[ticker], ['Suggest']] = "Hold"
    elif target_low(ticker) < current_price(ticker) < target_mid(ticker):
        Target_Frame.loc[[ticker], ['Suggest']] = "Consider"
```

Thank you!

Comment: What you would do is create `target_high` and friends as dictionaries.  Then you can do something like `target_high[ticker] = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you could use `np.where` or `.map` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303244/lambda-function-inside-map-pandas)) with the conditions inside, rather than creating separate variables.  So maybe something like this:

```py
Target_Frame["Suggest"] = np.where(
Target_Frame["Price"] > Target_Frame["High"], "Sell", # if above high then sell
np.where(Target_Frame["Price"] < Target_Frame["Low"], "Buy", # if below low then buy
np.where(Target_Frame["Price"].between(
Target_Frame["Median"], Target_Frame["High"]), "Hold", # if between median and high then hold
"Consider"))) # else consider
```